# Windows 10 Pro | Display language not being not changed

Tags: windows-10, language

I'm trying to change my display language but nothing works.
I've even tried to use the powershell with following commands:

```
Set-WinSystemLocale en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US -Force
```

Settings > Time and Language
[image: Settings > Time and Language]

Control Panel Settings > Welcome & New User
[image: Control Panel Settings > Welcome & New User]

Control Panel Settings > Region

[image: Control Panel Settings > Region]

Comment: If you create a new user is the interface  English?

Comment: Just added a new user. The interface is completely in German for the new user as well.

Comment: it seems that these methods are what I  can found so far, have you ever tried installed the newest update package?

Comment: I've tried everything. I even did a clean install a week ago. I'm currently running Version 1909 (18363.1256) and there are no updates available.

Comment: Did you figure it out?